# Store a text lines in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have some texts which contain some lines. There is a word in every line. I should copy the text and then paste it to the Eclipse Console Output window and finally store each line in an array.

I don't know how many lines does each text have. How could I do this?

I know if I want to store some strings to an array I should do like bellow, but I don't want to do by this method:

```
String[] Lines = {"line1", "line2", ....};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how many lines you will have you could use a generic list.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This will resize dynamically as you add values to it.

You could also use arrays and do the resizing yourself, which is what the ArrayList does behind the scenes, it's just that it adds complexity to your code.

Comment: And then add it with lines.add(string);

Comment: btw. if you use Java7+ you could write also List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1):

You can not change an array size after you initialize it. If you change your previous data will be lost. You can use ArrayList to add items dynamically. For example;

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //read your file here and print it. After that;
    list.add(line); // I assumed you get lines to a variable called line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDk 7+ you could easily do this by

```
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(new File("test.txt").toPath());
```

But if you still want to use array convert that list to array like

```
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(new File("test.txt").toPath());
String[] str = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Or if you dont have a file and copy pasting to console try this

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(s.hasNextLine()){
    String line = s.nextLine();
    if(line.length() > 0) {
        lines.add(s.nextLine());
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(lines);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to import them from a .txt file, I want to paste them to the Eclipse Console Output window and then store then in an array.